# How to draw a graph of Fixed Point in LaTeX?

Tags: pgfplots

[image]
I want to draw a graph this function Tx = (x^2) - 2, latex, not include image in latex

Answer (score 2):

Version with the package **tzplot** ([link to the CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/tzplot)), based on **tikz** (but with a syntax shortened according to the package author):

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tzplot}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tzfn[blue,thick]{(\x)^2-2}[-2.6:2.6]
    \tzfn[red,thick]{\x}[-5:5]
    \tzshoworigin*{0}[al](0pt) 
    \tzaxes[-](-5,-5)(5,5)
    \tzticks*(-2pt:0pt){-5,...,5}(-2pt:0pt){-5,...,5}
    \tzticksx(-4pt:0pt){-4,-2,2,4}[b=5pt]
    \tzticksy(-4pt:0pt){-4,-2,2,4}[l=3pt]
    \tznode(5,0){$x$}[b=5pt]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Note:** `\tzshoworigin[al]` don't display the "origin" at "**a**bove **l**eft" (bug?), but at "bottom left" so I need to use the starred syntax, which display by default no text but a dot, so I specify the text with `{0}`, and the size of the dot (with `(0pt)` to hide it).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \draw[step=2,gray!20] (-4,-4) grid (4,4); % comment if grid is not desired
        \draw[line width=1pt] (-4,0)--(4,0);
        \foreach \x in {-4,-2,...,4} \draw (\x,0)--(\x,-0.1) node[below] {\footnotesize $\x$};
        \draw[line width=1pt] (0,-4)--(0,4);
        \clip (-4,-4) rectangle (4,4);
        \foreach \x in {-4,-2,...,4} \draw (0,\x)--(-0.1,\x) node[left] {\footnotesize $\x$};
        \draw[line width=2pt] plot[smooth] (\x,\x*\x-2);
        \draw[line width=2pt,red] plot (\x,\x);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```